# Create JSON object or string..?

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0, json.net

Can we initialize JSON object with a string in C# ;

like:       `"Person": [{"age":"42","name":"John"}]`

as        `object  JsonData = "Person": [{"age":"42","name":"John"}];`

???

So that i can give this JSON object directly to the   `DatacontractJSONSerializer`

And i could get the data out of it.!

---

```
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>{
                   new Person{age  = 1, name  = "Scott"},
                   new Person{age = 2, name  = "Bill"}
                   };




            string jsonString = ExtensionMethods.JSONHelper.ToJSON(people);


         }

    }
}
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class JSONHelper
    {
        public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(obj);
        }

        public static string ToJSON(this object obj, int recursionDepth)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.RecursionLimit = recursionDepth;
            return serializer.Serialize(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

So,

```
string jsonString = ExtensionMethods.JSONHelper.ToJSON(people);
```

Gives a string of :      `[{},{}]`

Empty data structure, Any idea..?

Comment: you question can be rephrased as. " How do I initialize a JSON object in C#"

Answer (score 0):

With extension methods, you want to patch your method onto the type that you intend to call that method against. In this case, `IEnumerable` is a good place to add methods you want to use on a List:

```
public class Person {
  public int age { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
}

public static class JSONHelper {
  public static string ToJSON(this IEnumerable obj) {
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
  }
}

void Main() {
  List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
    new Person() { age = 1, name = "Scott" },
    new Person() { age = 2, name = "Bill" }
  };

  // [{"age":1,"name":"Scott"},{"age":2,"name":"Bill"}]
  string json = people.ToJSON();
}
```

The important distinction is that you should use the extension method against a variable of the type it's defined against.  You shouldn't reference the extension method directly.

Comment: Dave :       List<Person> people = new List<Person>{
                   new Person{age  = 1, name  = "Scott"},
                   new Person{age = 2, name  = "Bill"}
                   };




            string jsonString = people.ToJSON();

            
         }



    }
    public static class JSONHelper
    {
        public static string ToJSON(this IEnumerable<Person> obj)
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
        }
    }
}

Comment: DaveWard:    the above code still gives me the previous result.    [{},{}]